# Redefine a given unit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to redefine the electron mass unit in siunitx so that it is `\mathrm{m}_0` instead of the default `\mathrm{m}_\mathrm{e}`. How do I do that?

Comment: `\DeclareSIUnit{\Electronmass}{\mathrm{m}_o}` and `\si{Electronmass}`

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `\electronmass` is

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\electronmass}{\text{\ensuremath{m_{\text{e}}}}}
```

Just change it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\electronmass}{\text{\ensuremath{m_{0}}}}

\begin{document}
\SI{2}{\electronmass}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you must realize you're changing a standard symbol. And this shouldn't be done.

Comment: Even if I do not change a standard symbol and give it another name, your approach looks weird when I have an exponent for my unit, e.g. $\SI{2}{\electronmass^2}$ (the original symbols have that too...). Is that intentionally (and by this I mean should it be that way due to some convention)?